# Close a BottomSheet containing a DraggableScrollableSheet in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am displaying a BottomSheet containing a DraggableScrollableSheet by using showButtomSheet. I would like to close the BottomSheet by a click on a button on the DarggableScrollableSheet. How can I do this?

I am able to make it work as long as the DraggableScrollableSheet is not close to the top of the screen, but when it gets near the top, a modal-kind-of-overlay appears beneath the sheet, and when I close the sheet, the modal overlay stays.

I have tried using the PersistentBottomSheetController.close() to close the Sheet and with Navigator.pop as shown below, but the result is the same: A dark overlay stays after the sheet has been closed, and I can't find a way to remove it.

Dartpad: http://dartpad.dev/7ec436f3c850936d74dcdbb6ff17f97c

Screen recording: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE1VE.gif

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>(
                (BuildContext context) {

              return DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  expand: false,
                  maxChildSize: 0.935,
                  builder: (context, scrollController) => ListView(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 200,
                        color: Colors.amber[600],
                        child: Center(
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 500,
                        color: Colors.amber[500],
                        child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to change the close action to this:

```
ElevatedButton(
    child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
    onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Scaffold.of(context).showBodyScrim(false, 0.0);
    }
),
```

When the BottomSheet is dragged all the way to the top, the Scaffold adds a ModalBarrier beneath the BottomSheet. The ModalBarrier can be controlled with ScaffoldState method showBodyScrim: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBodyScrim.html

Answer (score 0):

Change `Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>` to `showModalBottomSheet`

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
  isDismissible: false,
  context: context, 
  builder: (context)=> ...,
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, modal is not an option, because it should be possible to interact with the content beneath when the sheet is halfway open.